# Python & openpyxl: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, tuples, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, openpyxl

[Short code depicting my issue (IMAGE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue8D3.png)

Please bear with me I don't know how to copy to code from the Jupyter notebook so it is in an image.

I am using windows 10, Anaconda & the Jupyter notebook

I am creating a for loop to gather data from cells in openpyxl which was not working.  I changed it to a simple for loop on line 370 which still does not work.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks

Richard

edit:

```
import openpyxl
import os

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('book1.xlsx')
wb.sheetnames
sheet = wb['S1']
sheet.max_row
rows = sheet.max_row

for i in range (10):
    print('hello')
```

---

> ```
> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-370-46746f9a7864> in <module>()
>           1 for i in range (10):
>     ----> 2     print('hello')
>
>     TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
> ```

Comment: Can you get some raw code for us to run? I appreciate you sharing the png, but some copy-pastable code would be best!

Comment: Edited to show code :)

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe ('hello') is being treated as a tuple? Maybe you are using an version of python that doesn't recognize print's parenthesis?

Comment: Initialize an int variable before this and see if your loop can just increment that. I'm just curious to see if that stops the tuple error.

Comment: Looks like you've previously accidentally assigned a tuple to the name `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Accidently assigned a tuple to the name `print`

confirmed:

```
type(print)
```

returns `tuple`

-jasonharper

Comment: Where? I don't see where that is happening with the code you posted.

Comment: Presumable I changed it earlier and deleted it.  Since it was on Jupyter notebook a simple 'Restart Kernel' reset all the varialbes and I was on my way again.